# How do I get the index of the current item in relation to the parent element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, parent-child, parent

I am trying to get the index of the current item within

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#a">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#e">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am using jQuery and have got the total by simply using

```
$('ul#navbar').children().length;
```

How do I get the current index in relation to the parent element?

eg. Third link is clicked, 3 is returned or 2 if as an array.

I've tried the following but keep returning -1 for not found

```
$('ul#navbar a').click(function(){
    var curPos = $(this).parent().parent().index($(this).parent());
});
```

EDIT: Changed the ul.navbar in the javascript to ul#navbar, apologies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `index()` method on the parent `li` element

```
var curPos = $(this).parent().index();
```

http://api.jquery.com/index/

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Comment: this would always return zero. You need to invoke `.parent()` to index the `li` node.

Answer (score 3):

If you have no other anchors inside the navbar,

```
$('#navbar a').click( function () {
    var curpos = $('#navbar a').index(this);
});
```

If you have nested anchors, as are common in navbars, this will do:

```
$('#navbar>li>a').click( function () {
    var curpos = $('#navbar>li>a').index(this);
});
```

Comment: this one is more accurate and worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're trying to access `ul.navbar` but the `ul` has no class named `navbar`. To access it by ID, use the ID selector `#`

Also, you just need to use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index) which gets the index of the current element in relation to it's siblings. Use the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent) to get the `li` and then access the index of that.

```
$('ul#navbar a').click(function(){
    var curPos = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(curPos);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/SyvZ5/

Comment: Apologies that was a typo, it's actually a nested nav like dheerosaur mentions but just truncated it

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('ul#navbar a').click(function(){
        var curPos = $(this).parent().index();
    });
});
```

should do the trick.