# Where is the position of the child element? - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i get child element `position` in JQuery?
I want to get the number 2 in the alert, because it is the second child!

```js
function where_am_i(element) {
  alert("your position is:" + $(element).position_element());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li onclick="where_am_i(this)">two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the index of the current item in relation to the parent element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470917/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-current-item-in-relation-to-the-parent-element-wit)

Comment: @SuperStormer Nop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery's [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method. Note that it returns a zero-based index so you'll need to add one to get the value you want.

```js
$("ul li").on("click", function() {
  alert(`your position is: ${$(this).index() + 1}`)
})
```

```css
li { margin: 1rem auto; cursor: pointer; }
li:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

---

As always, [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const target = e.target.closest("li")
  if (target) { // clicked on an <li>
    const siblings = Array.from(target.parentElement.children)
    const position = siblings.indexOf(target) + 1
    alert(`your position is: ${position}`)
  }
})
```

```css
li { margin: 1rem auto; cursor: pointer; }
li:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh shoot I forgot about the .index method. Haven't used jQuery in a looooong time haha

Comment: @mstephen19 Do you have a replacement for jQuery?

Comment: @mrx Personally, I wouldn't recommend using jQuery in 2022. I don't even see why anyone would use it. Check out libraries like React or Vue

Comment: @mstephen19 I'd rather recommend vanilla JS as an alternative to jQuery. Vue and React serve totally different needs

Comment: @mrx I've added a vanilla JS version to my answer

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Phil's solution is much better

Get the parent, get all the parent's children, then find the index of the inputted element within the array of child nodes.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li onclick="findElem(this)">two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>

<script>
    const findElem = (elem) => {
        // Grab the parent element
        const parent = $(elem).parent();

        // Get array of all its children
        const allChildren = $(parent).children();

        // Turn it into a regular array, find the index of our elem, add 1 to it
        const position = [...allChildren].indexOf(elem) + 1;

        console.log(`The clicked element's position is ${position}`);
    };
</script>
```